# Where is source location?

Tags: html

```
<audio controls>
<source src="vincent.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
<source src="vincent.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
</audio>
```

Where is my source location? On GoDaddy? On my computer?

Comment: If you only see the filenames, then your HTML expects those files to be right next to it - in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Source file must be in the same directory of the file that you put this code [illustrative img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mA78E.jpg) if you use a server to host your site the same logic applies, you can also use a subdirectory like a folder "myfolder" and add this the location in the source like that

```
<audio controls>
<source src="myfolder/vincent.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
```

There is another ways to access a file that is out of the folder using for example ../ to step back or using ./ to make the path start in the root folder

```
 <audio controls>
 <source src="../myfolder/vincent.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
 </audio>
```

[UPDATE] Try this in your index.html in the Server after that try to access your domain "http://stevegilman.net/index.html" if still dosen't work keep the files like that that I'll will check, but try others browsers like Firefox or Opera to test

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Audio Test</title>

</head>
<body>

<audio controls>
<source src="http://stevegilman.net/thinking_of_you_test.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>

</audio>
</body>
</html>
```

[UPDATE 2] the first source code is my with only one type of Double Quotes your is below with two types of Quotes, Curly and Stright Quotes

[image]

Comment: See my problem here:  http://stevegilman.net/

Comment: In your first code you have the source with this path "stevegilman.net/ Thinking of you cd 4. mp3" just remove "stevegilman.net"  or add a folder with this name,  after that rename your file without spaces  like that "thinking_of_you_cd4.mp3 " notice that I add underscore instead of space  and remove the capital letters e don't forget to put the same name in the your mp3 file  "thinking_of_you_cd4.mp3" your second code have the same problem you put alot of name in the path  /home/stevegilman/public... each name with the slash will be treated like a folder remove them all

Comment: I made the suggested changes. See the update at:  http://stevegilman.net/  Still doesn't work. Explorer still says invalid source.

Comment: I tested the code and works fine, including with your own file music "stevegilman.net/thinking_of_you_test.mp3" so try again with the code that I updated in the answer and try to test others browsers too – Kleber Germano 1 hour ago    Delete

Comment: Well I uploaded your code and it worked like a champ in all browsers! I am just learning HTML5 and this will be a lot of information for me to think about and try to understand. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me!! Thank you very, very much!

Comment: This is the line that was corrupt somehow:  <source src=“http://stevegilman.net/thinking_of_you_test.mp3" type=”audio/mp3"/> . When I put them in a document comparer they show as different but I can't see how. When I replaced that single line of my code with that single line of your code my code then works. But I still can't see how they differ.

Comment: You welcome, so about the difference between the two codes is that in your code you put two types of quotes one is Curly and the other is Straight, probably you copyed the code from web where the Curly Double Quotes are sometimes used, so you must have edited just one parte of the code in Text Editor or IDE where the stright quote is more often used, and as the Quotes dosen't match the code don't work I'll update the answer with a image of the difference

Comment: By the way, If the question was solve pls don't forget to mark the answer as the right one in the check symbol :)

Comment: Did I close this out correctly so you get your points? I am watching Youtubes to see how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Yes, when you checked the question as answered anyone that has the same problem will see that this question has the solution, this is why is important mark as "answered" besides that, some points for who asnwered the question isn't a bad thing, hehe

Comment: tks for your concern to close the question right, some fellas just get off with the answer without a feedback, good luck in your studies and any issue just come back